# Node at each end of arrow, Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-arrows

I'm drawing a vertical arrow and I want to have a node at each end, but tikz seems to be putting the lower node in funny places:

This is the arrow with the node above in the right place:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->] (0,-3.5) -- (0,2) node[above, scale = 1.3] {$\varepsilon$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to put a node at the bottom end of the line.  I can't work out where to put the second node command.  I've tried these two:

```
\draw[->] node[below]{$M$} (0,-3.5) -- (0,2) node[above, scale = 1.3] {$\varepsilon$};

\draw[->] (0,-3.5) -- (0,2) node[above, scale = 1.3] {$\varepsilon$} node[below]{$M$};
```

but the first one puts the node half-way along the line of the arrow and the second puts the node just below the arrowhead.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this \draw[->] (0,-3.5) node[below]{$M$}-- (0,2) node[above, scale = 1.3] {$\varepsilon$};

Comment: You can also use `\draw[->]  (0,-3.5) -- (0,2) node[above, scale = 1.3] {$\varepsilon$} node[pos=0,below] {$M$};`.

Comment: @Jesse, would you like to write an answer, or is there another question we might dupe this to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution. A node needs a coordinate to go with. The first trial has no associated coordinate (need to put the node after a coordinate), thus causing errors. The second trial has a coordinate to associate to, but it is associated to the top node because the line was drawn from bottom to top. In such case, Gonzalo Medina's solution is crucial where `pos=0` tells LaTeX to put the node at bottom. The whole length of line is considered to be 1. pos=0 means `positioning it at staring point`, `pos=0.5` means `positioning it at the mid point` while `pos=1` means `positioning at the end point`. `above, below, left and right` are for directional location, relative to the point of discussion.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%\draw[->] (0,-3.5) -- (0,2) node[above, scale = 1.3] {$\varepsilon$};

\draw[->] (0,-3.5) node[below]{$M$} -- (0,2) node[above, scale = 1.3] {$\varepsilon$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```